# Type a function that, given another function, returns a similar function as the given function without 1 argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to create a function (to be known as `outerFn`) that is given a function (to be known as `innerFn`) as an argument. The `innerFn` function is given an object type argument, and that object will be required to have a `user` parameter. The `outerFn` should then return a function (to be known as `returnFn`) that should have a similar type as `innerFn` but its argument object should *not* require the `user` parameter (but still require all other arguments).

I would like this so that my `outerFn` can return a `returnFn` that *actually* calls the `innerFn` but injects the `user` automatically (i.e. without me having to send the `user`)

ex.

```js
type User = { user: { id: number, name: string } };

type Place = { Place: string };
type UserAndPlace = User & Place;
type InnerFn1Resolve = { something: string };
type InnerFn1 = (args: UserAndPlace) => Promise<InnerFn1Resolve>;
const innerFn1: InnerFn1 = async (args) => Promise.resolve({ something: 'yes' });
type ReturnFn1 = (args: Place) => Promise<InnerFn1Resolve>;
const returnFn1: ReturnFn1 = outerFn(innerFn1);

type Job = { job: number };
type UserAndJob = User & Job;
type InnerFn2Resolve = { else: number };
type InnerFn2 = (args: UserAndJob) => Promise<InnerFn2Resolve>;
const innerFn2: InnerFn2 = async (args) => Promise.resolve({ else: 1 });
type ReturnFn2 = (args: Job) => Promise<InnerFn2Resolve>;
const returnFn2: ReturnFn2 = outerFn(innerFn2);
```

I have tried the following for the `outerFn`. The typing is correct for the above...but the `outerFn` return complains.

```js
type ArgsWithUser = Record<string, unknown> & User;
type InnerFn<Args extends ArgsWithUser, Response> = (args: Args) => Promise<Response>
type ReturnFn<Args extends ArgsWithUser, Response> = (args: Omit<Args, 'user'>) => Promise<Response>

const outerFn = <Args extends ArgsWithUser, Response>(innerFn: InnerFn<Args, Response>): ReturnFn<Args, Response> => {
    const user: User['user'] = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Something',
    };
    return async (argsWithoutUser) => innerFn({ ...argsWithoutUser, user });
};
```

I get the following error for the parameters of `innerFn` (i.e. `{ ...argsWithoutUser, user }`)

> Argument of type 'Omit<Args, "user"> & { user: User; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Args'.
> 'Omit<Args, "user"> & { user: User; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Args', but 'Args' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ArgsWithUser'.ts(2345)

I just...really don't understand the error. I get that it's trying to say that the return value might not exactly match `Args`...but I also don't see why that would be the case and feel like I must be messing up the types in some way.

I can cast the object as `Args` but would like to avoid casting if it isn't necessary (and I don't believe it should be).

Here's a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3lArgxAuDKASwBMCA7LAWwCMkAaKcgQyogLmESPIHMoAvoIDcAKFGhIUAIKJecAOpFgAC3hJUUAEoQAxgHtEJADydufRlnIBrcvoDu5AHxQAZLFxjJ0AJLlySABi5May8lAQAB7AEOQkcDJyispquIw6cGD65AguaAAUzEkEYXAAlKguAAqI+lRECMYZWTkQThLg0DrAWIjkwaFJEdGx8YnySqrqiOkQmdm5moXFUADy9cCD8owA5DhIO04VKNW19Y3NC23iBjnAUPpYMYjBmlsJUTFxCaWTqQzaOYtXL5HgBF7kAh+cEDUqzeatI4Ebq9fohOGAhGLE4YURQfFQW6cbC4AjTADae1wOwAupp0HiCUzSAQAIz0RlM-EsNgEHYAZTqEFUPF4Ow5TIEYiZiGFqKgzDgIHIuigywmKUewGmxxcYKC5HymAAdKaihrVFrppZcIIymIpeJvFAqgAbZi6aBoTBuj3sKBmUUiDpSabSOK+z2aaZuF3uz1eTpQaEG1kZfSugBuXsIcCFIr4HC4QcdzpTENZS3NcDJuHDJEjEF1LrODQgxnLwTTcwz2acYiJ931Fah-lTmkVytV6vKlRbdTbxtleazECNAfzKlFfJAcx2dsTUhRfS7VZWjebNQXjU75G7K77A4W91lPRPd+RcvflbQWoNoLHCt7SdJMACl9BoekoAAKwgihqDoZBSyTMM4nAyC0Bjdx0MPXxAOCAAmdNVygiBXQQeDaA0ZCpFvAiz3kWskHrdDL1bG98PIIie1XftREHYhOII0cYS4iclRVNVqzY68ICXHjs3XMiKKgSsBGA51jzReiCmrAhWLnK9znbOjiMffjnygV9UUIz8320zQ-whADRII+0gA) recreation where you can see the error.

What I am specifically trying to figure out is *why* the typings are incorrect. I've been working with TypeScript for 3+ years and think I have a pretty good understanding generally on why typings are wrong...but in this instance, I can't seem to wrap my head around why what I have is wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you [edit] to clarify whether you are primarily looking to give typings that work (and not worry too much about your failed attempt) or are you primarily looking for an explanation of why your attempt failed (and not worry too much about fixing it)?  Probably a good answer will address both to some extent, but they are separate issues and question and answer should focus on a single well-defined issue.

Comment: (see prev comment).  [This playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvxDkN) both demonstrates what the typing issue is with your attempt and what a possible fix would be... which one should we focus on?

Comment: @jcalz I have updated my question (see "Edit 2"). But essentially I want both a reason why the typings don't work and any help that will get me to a typing that _will_ work without the casting. The playground that you gave me does get rid of the error but the `returnFn` still requires the `{ user: User }` to be sent, which is what I'd like to avoid. Thank you for the effort you've put in already and any additional help would be much appreciated.

Comment:  Maybe I didn't communicate properly? You should ask a *single* well-defined question in order for it to be suitable here, else it will possibly be closed as needing focused.  I was asking you to identify which of your two questions is the primary one, but it seems you've explicitly said "I want both", which is exactly what I tried to avoid.  Could you please pick one? My answer will certainly touch on both, but only *delve* into one. •• Please show me how my solution requires `{user: User}` to be sent; as far as I know it does not, [see here](https://tsplay.dev/wR7yxN). Could you clarify?

Comment: @jcalz, my bad. I've updated my answer to be more specific. What I really want to know is _why_ what I have doesn't work. Of course, the offshoot of that is that I'd like a fix, but I also feel like that if I can understand what is wrong with mine, I can probably debug and fix from there. As for your's requiring the user. I was talking about the error at the bottom but looking at it again, it looks like you intentionally forced the error. I _do_ see that another usage works. Unfortunately when plugged into my code it still doesn't so maybe I did that wrong. I will give it another attempt.

Comment: So then if [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WoxyPw) explains the reason for the compiler error, I will write up an answer explaining that, with my refactored version as a possible fix, without worrying too much about whether that refactored version is actually suitable for your underlying use case.  Does that work for you?

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is technically correct.  The compiler cannot be sure that the argument type of `innerFn` will actually accept a general `User` for its `user` property.  Here is an example of the situation the compiler is worried about:

```
const innerFn = async (arg: {
    user: { id: number, name: "a" | "b" }
}) => ({ a: 1, b: 2 }[arg.user.name]).toFixed(2);
```

Here `innerFn` requires that its argument be of type `{ user: { id: number, name: "a" | "b" } }`.  This is strictly narrower than `User`.  If you try to call `innerFn()` with an argument of type `User`, there's a good chance you'll get a runtime error.  If if `arg.user.name` is neither `"a"` nor `"b"` then you will dereference `undefined` and get a `TypeError`.

But your typings for `outerFn()` happily accept `innerFn`:

```
const returnFn = outerFn(innerFn); // no compiler error
```

The type `Args` is inferred as `{user: {id: number; name: "a" | "b"}}`, and `Omit<Args, "user"> & { user: { id: number; name: string; }; }` is just the same as `User`.  But that's not what `innerFn` needs.  That is, the problem is that

```
//  'Omit<Args, "user"> & { user: { id: number; name: string; }; }' is assignable to the constraint of 
//  type 'Args', but 'Args' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ArgsWithUser'.
```

And so if you run `returnFn()` you will get that runtime error, without a compiler warning:

```
returnFn({}).catch(e => console.log(e)) // no compiler error, but:
//  (intermediate value)[arg.user.name] is undefined
```

So that's the problem.  This is admittedly unlikely so you might want to just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (what you called "cast"ing) and move on.

---

If instead you want to refactor to avoid this problem, you can do so in a way that doesn't run afoul of this by *adding* `User` to a type instead of *omitting* it:

```
type InnerFn<A, R> = (args: A & User) => Promise<R>
type ReturnFn<A, R> = (args: A) => Promise<R>

const outerFn = <A, R>(innerFn: InnerFn<A, R>): ReturnFn<A, R> => {
    const user: User['user'] = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Something',
    };
    return async (argsWithoutUser) => innerFn({ ...argsWithoutUser, user });
};
```

This compiles with no error, and still works for the examples you present. This may or may not actually work for your use case, but at least the compiler is happy.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-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-Q8RSTAISAgJSMlI8Q7wkQ9pDkaB1V+yqmm0eVVOJN1cnqc5lzgboYjHB8hl+CBxgibHkgxHa6Xx5xCd9bpyZ+UYqacGn5TijjizQJnuYw2ciUw0kCapenaQl5mWTXBU+Zcg5+S5YVRUNBU3NlTWJW8lV1TYLU+F1XWDX1bbTQXK0bSqVEA1wB9XQJD0oG9T1fXtyFA1rBwDoSfRcwm9LFDUFHRSgBQw-kHzfH4IPElUg5jDKKPw7QITYjT+QA70HHxfIaUGiuz6zsIOANWNld2t8vhzdmOncYJaVHCJghk9T6P-pZCnOc8JvsiL44S7OXOLoQ53B7F2cW-nC0baJ9nhk5z0qxH12K6NxM+AIJ4QGOIL-dpowaV22fbfMAhs+787e7GAfC+LtRS4iMe+cts-qSQulz7Ql3J8LrBcygBeDcAAI7YCwFbW-oPV218CAnhoLIW82ECyxnjGA8SGBla4CEEmMsFZjSkUgcfaAAApVQEcABWqgKC7j9mPJOuAU4kHITQRwmcoCsIYY3Au74n6lwjhANQCBaEeWQAnBuRgH6fnaKzMczDWFL0pv3Xh-DR68w5GpbI75p5uhkWaeeS5fRKJXmvZ+EBXZCJEVAFuR9E501PnSfRbdOGqBMffVRw9zGvw0QhD+Tiv4M20Y4P+2QRZ6KAYkAsEDwGgKgUE8g75XbULfDY98ABmEMYZUFxigBgkIWDcDtxwcFRC5ZKyQTyXEnQAggA)